# Why Does SmtpFailedRecipientException.FailedRecipient Include Angle Brackets?

Tags: c#, email, smtpclient

I have a .NET 4.0 application which sends email with the SmtpClient.Send() method.  Sometimes our SMTP server will return an error like "550 Unknown user", so I wrote a handler which catches SmtpFailedRecipientsException and looks at the FailedRecipient property of each of the SmtpFailedRecipientException objects within SmtpFailedRecipientsException.InnerExceptions, to determine if the failure was because of a To address, a CC address, or a Bcc address.  (We want to handle BCC failures separately.)

The [FailedRecipient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpfailedrecipientexception.failedrecipient%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) property is documented to be "A String that contains the e-mail address."  However, I've found that my attempts to determine which kind of recipient failed is failing because FailedRecipient is including angle brackets, so it looks like "<failedrecipient@domain.com>" instead of "failedrecipient@domain.com"!  Is it correct that that property should include angle brackets, so that all consumers of that property have to check to see if they're there and then strip them off before it's useful?

**EDIT**

Ugh... okay, if [referencesource.microsoft.com](http://referencesource.microsoft.com) is to be believed, and the code hasn't changed from 4.0 to 4.5.1, then I think I've found what's causing the problem.  The [SmtpClient.Send()](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/System/R/cca069628a6b9b57.html) method calls [SmtpTransport.SendMail()](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/System/net/System/Net/mail/SmtpTransport.cs.html#eb69bd2f50005459) to communicate with the SMTP server.  Since the SMTP protocol requires that the RCPT TO: command have its email address parameter delimited with angle brackets, SmtpTransport.SendMail() calls the internal method [MailAddress.GetSmtpAddress()](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/System/net/System/Net/mail/MailAddress.cs.html#8dbe43f7ebbfeb8d) to get the value to send to the SMTP server:

```
internal string GetSmtpAddress(bool allowUnicode)
{
    return String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "<{0}>", GetAddress(allowUnicode));
}
```

But if the RCPT TO: command fails, then SmtpTransport.SendMail() populates the SmtpFailedRecipientException with this calculated "SMTP address", instead of the MailAddress.Address property!

Is this a bug-report-worthy problem?

**EDIT Dec 15 2014**

I opened [Connect bug 970353](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedbackdetail/view/970353/smtpfailedrecipientexception-failedrecipient-includes-angle-brackets) three months ago, and gave them code to reproduce the issue.  No word yet.

Comment: Maybe this will shed some light - it looks to be expected:  http://ask-leo.com/why_are_email_addresses_sometimes_in_anglebrackets.html  In any event, you can check the string for angle brackets and remove them to get the e-mail address.

Comment: @Tim, I know it's valid to include a "friendly name" (I think the RFC calls it a "display name"?) in an email address, but that is not the email address that was submitted to the Send() method.  The method or the exception added those angle brackets, and I'd like to know why...

Answer (score 0):

Mail servers often present email addresses in this format to clients: `"John Smith" <john.smith@domain.com>`.

You should expect addresses of this format to maybe come back.  You could try passing the string you receive to the `System.Net.Mail.MailAddress` class to parse it for you:

`string emailAddress = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("\"John Smith\" <john.smith@domain.com>").Address;`

There's further information on this class [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailaddress%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: I know it's valid to include a "friendly name" (I think the RFC calls it a "display name"?) in an email address, but that is not the email address that was submitted to the Send() method. The method or the exception added those angle brackets, and I'd like to know why... If the Framework is not going to hand back a MailAddress object, but instead just a string, it's unexpected (to me) that that string should be different than what it was given.  Thanks for the idea of letting MailAddress parse away the angle brackets, though.

Comment: It's possible that the FailedRecipient property is populated from some data returned by the server, in which case the framework has no control over the change, and its behaviour in what I'd imagine is the most correct way by telling you what the server said the failed recipient was, rather than the recipient that was sent to the server in the original request.